# Spring Boot Apache Artemis Embedded JMS Queue Eample

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I am trying to set up a simple Spring Boot application that uses an embedded JMS Queue. I am successful with HornetQ but when I try to convert to Artemis I am getting a failure on the ArtemisConnectionFactory. Here is my code that I use for HornetQ. Any help would be appreciative.

```
package com.comporium.log.server;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

import com.comporium.log.server.services.LogListener;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Autowired
LogListener logListener;

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListener() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(this.connectionFactory);
    container.setDestinationName("loggerQueue");
    container.setMessageListener(logListener);
    return container;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me your code worked. To test the application I have added a `CommandLineRunner` which produces a message.

```
@Bean
CommandLineRunner sendMessage(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    return args -> {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("loggerQueue", "Message to Artemis");
    };
}
```

The consumer will consume the message sent to this queue. It it not necessary to declare any properties, but I have defined the following compile time dependencies on my project:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis')
compile('org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server')
```